# Strange situation with __utmz cookie on browsers

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, cookies, google-analytics

I have try to get reference keyword from Google Analytics using PHP `$_COOKIE['__utmz']` and next jquery.cookie plugin but both ways failed.

Here is situation with PHP (as everybody knows need to reload pate to obtain cookie value):

1. Firefox

   - going to any search engine, type desired keyword, choose proper URL;
   - landing page - no cookie present;
   - going to any other page - cookie present - can obtain reference key;
   - closing FF
   - going to any search engine, type another keyword, choose proper URL;
   - landing page - no cookie present;
   - going to any other page - cookie present - can obtain reference, but what I see - is this same cookie from the first visit;
2. Internet Explorer

   - going to any search engine, type desired keyword, choose proper URL;
   - landing page - no cookie present;
   - going to any other page - cookie still is not present;
   - closing IE;
   - going to any search engine, type another keyword, choose proper URL;
   - landing page - no cookie present;
   - going to any other page - cookie present - but the reference keyword is from first visit;
3. Chrome

   - is not working at all (cookie is not set) :/

Here is situation with jQuery.cookie script (instant cookie load):

1. Firefox

   - going to any search engine, type desired keyword, choose proper URL;
   - landing page - cookie present - can obtain reference key;
   - closing FF
   - going to any search engine, type another keyword, choose proper URL;
   - landing page - cookie present - can obtain reference, but what I see - is this same cookie from the first visit;
2. Internet Explorer

   - going to any search engine, type desired keyword, choose proper URL;
   - landing page - cookie present but values are empty;
   - going to any other page - same problem;
   - closing IE;
   - going to any search engine, type another keyword, choose proper URL;
   - landing page - cookie present but values are empty;
   - going to any other page - same problem;
3. Chrome

   - is not working at all (cookie is not set) :/

Finalizing all above:

1. Why cookie persists on FF?
2. What happened to cookie on IE?
3. Why Chrome doesn't let to use GA cookie?

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using for jQuery.cookie to read the cookie values? I suspect you're reading it before it's set. Since gA is async you might need to push that logic into _gaq so it executes after the _trackPageview and ensure the cookie is created.

Answer (score 0):

Makes sense... the first time a searcher lands on your page, the __utmz cookie will not have been set yet, so $_COOKIE will not be populated with it. Once they've retrieved/processsed this landing page, the google analytics code will kick in and set the __utm? cookies. On the NEXT hit on any of your pages, that cookie will be sent to the server and be present in $_COOKIE.

Some talk about the cookies and their lifetime [here](http://www.morevisibility.com/analyticsblog/from-__utma-to-__utmz-google-analytics-cookies.html)

Comment: I think the OP does understand that, his question is more the different behavior across various browsers :)

Comment: Yes, NikiC, that is what I'm asking about :)